# Expected value of a random variable is element of its rage (open interval).

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow I \subset  \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable random variable where $I$ is an open Interval. I'm looking for a simple argument why $\mathbb{E}[X] \in I$. Is this sufficient or are there alternative arguments:

$$
\inf I \leq \inf X(\Omega) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\Omega) \leq \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \sup X(\Omega) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\Omega) \leq \sup I.
$$

Comment: This does not exclude that e.g. $\mathbb EX=\inf I\notin I$ if $I$ is an open interval. What info do you have for $I$? Is it indeed an interval?

Comment: I updated the question. My main problem is that all I can conclude from this is $\mathbb{E}[X] \in \bar{I}$.

Comment: Start with $inf\ I\lt X\lt sup\ I$, with strict inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $X$ is a nonnegative random variable with $X(\omega)<1$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Then evidently $0\leq\mathbb EX\leq1$.

Now assume that $\mathbb EX=1$.

We will reduce a contradiction so that we are allowed to conclude that $0\leq\mathbb EX<1$.

Let $r\in(0,1)$ and $B_r=\{X\leq r\}$.

Then $X\leq r\mathbf1_{B_r}+\mathbf1_{B_r^{\complement}}$ and from this it folows that:$$1=\mathbb EX\leq rP(B_r)+P(B_r^{\complement})=1+(r-1)P(B_r)$$
This implies that $P(B_r)=0$.

But we have $\Omega=\{X<1\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{1-\frac1n}$ so this leads to $P(\Omega)=0$ and a contradiction is found.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=(a,b)$.  For all $\Omega,a\lt X(\Omega)\lt b$, therefore $a\lt E(X)\lt b$.

$E(X)$ by definition is an average.  All the numbers going into the average are in the interval, so the average has to be within the interval.

Comment: As long as a proof of this lacks this answer is only a restatement of the question that was posed.

Comment: @drhab 9  I expanded my "proof" by stating the obvious.

Comment: Mwahhh... I removed the downvote, but are not willing to upvote. Terms like "expectation" and/or "average" of course give a strong indication that $a<\mathbb EX<b$ in this context but cannot be marked as a formal mathematical proof of that. This especially if we are dealing with continuous random variables where expectation is an integral. I leave further judgment to others.

Comment: @drhab Expectation is by definition average, so I cannot envision what a "formal" proof would look like other than by stating the obvious.  The average of a set of numbers, all of which are within some range, has to be within that range.

Comment: Then what is the formal definition of  "average" for a continuous random variable? You might as well turn things around and say that average is expectation by definiton. If you cannot envision what a formal proof would look like then have a look at my answer.

Comment: $drhab You are right